# How to change very long String to Integer

Tags: java

How to make this work?

```
long l = Long.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(myBytes), 16));
textField.setText("" + l);
```

It is throwing `NumberFormatException` because it is too long.

Comment: Because it cannot be represented by a long. Convert it to a BigInteger

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-int-)

Comment: @user7 No.  The exception happens because the value can't be represented by an `int`.  There's a world of difference between "too big for `int`" and "too big for `long`", and in this case, it may be a world worth exploring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use BigInteger for such cases. It is slow in performance, but solves the purpose perfectly

There is a constructor of BigInteger which accepts String and create instance with value passed as String:

BigInteger(String val)

You can follow the documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: How to convert it to BigInteger

Comment: @WitoldStrumiński Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem may be that you're trying to convert your number first to an `int`, then afterwards to a `long`.  This will only work for numbers up to about 2 billion, because that's the biggest number that fits in an `int`.

If your number will fit in a `long` (up to about 19 digits), but not an `int`, then you should be using the `parseLong` method of the `Long` class, instead of `parseInt`.

```
long myLong = Long.parseLong(myHexString, 16);
```

However, if the value is too big for a `long`, you'll need the `BigInteger` class.

```
BigInteger myInteger = new BigInteger(myHexString, 16);
```

Choose carefully.  `long` values tend to perform much better than `BigInteger` values, so if you know that there's no chance your value will exceed the largest possible `long`, then you may wish to choose `long`.